# Performance of IN (Array) in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, sorting

For example I have this table

```
Person
id: integer (primary key)
name: varchar
workplace_id: integer
```

and I want to find the name of people which work in some places, so I used this query

```
SELECT name FROM Person WHERE workplace_id IN(/*values*/)
```

Is it better to sort the values first? Or does sorting the values not make any difference in performance? How about the time complexity of the `IN` operator? If sorting makes better performance, is it considered a premature optimization and should be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting the list of values will probably be a net loss, since sorting costs time and the ordering of the list won't influence the performance.

The best optimization would be an index on `workplace_id`.

If the number of values is really large, it might be better to create a temporary table with the list values and join that table with your table.

To test all these options, use `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` that way the database will tell you how it solves the problem and how long each step takes.

Answer (score 0):

The in operator check all element in the array , for performance you maybe change the statement to use exist with another table.

```
SELECT name FROM Person a WHERE exist (select 1 from table b where b.workplace_id = a.workplace_id);
```

This going to check first match only.

Comment: do you have any source documenting this behavior?

Comment: @CapiEtheriel yes, you can see it here: 

"The subquery will generally only be executed long enough to determine whether at least one row is returned, not all the way to completion."

References: 
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-subquery.html#AEN16782 
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-comparisons.html#AEN16964

Comment: and what about the IN behavior?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-comparisons.html#AEN16964

Comment: the IN documentation says it is the same as `COLUMN = VALUE1 OR COLUMN = VALUE2 OR ...`. now, the OR evaluation order is _unpredictable_ but it seems to short circuit indeed (but not to the left, as devs would expect). see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL